# Better way of building dynamic PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to build a dynamic PDO SQL statement. Any idea on how to do it better?

I keep getting `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } free` when I run this...

So my MySQL PDO statement doesn't seem to be working well!

Any idea on how to fix this?

```
$park = $_POST["park"];
$lecturestyle_id = $_POST["lecturestyle"];
$group_size = $_POST["groupsize"];
$roomstructure_id = $_POST["roomstructure"];
$array = explode(",", $_POST["facilities"]);

// change Mon here

echo '<td class="gridSide">
Mon
';

// build facilities search

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){  
    if ($array[$i]!=0) {
    $fac .= 'AND facilities_id='.$array[$i].' ';
    }
    else
    $fac .= '';
}

echo '</td>';


for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) 
{

        // change mon here

        echo '<td class="box" id="mon'.$i.'">';

        // dynamically build sql query

        $sql = 
        "
        SELECT * FROM ts_room rm
        LEFT JOIN ts_roomfacilities rf
        ON rm.id = rf.room_id
        LEFT join ts_facilities f
        ON f.id = rf.facilities_id
        LEFT JOIN ts_building b
        ON rm.building_id=b.id
        WHERE capacity>=".$group_size.' ';

        $sql .= $fac;

        if($park!="Any") {
        $sql .= " AND b.park_id=".$park;
        }

        if($lecturestyle_id!="Any") {
        $sql .= " AND lecturestyle_id=".$lecturestyle_id;
        }

        if($roomstructure_id!="Any") {
        $sql .= " AND roomstructure_id=".$roomstructure_id;
        }

        $sql .= " AND rm.id NOT IN
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM ts_request rq
         LEFT JOIN ts_allocation a ON a.request_id = rq.id
         WHERE 
         day_id=1 AND period_id=".$i."
         OR a.status IS NOT NULL
         AND a.status IN ('Pending','Declined','Failed'))";

         $stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
         $rows = $stm->fetchColumn();

         echo $rows.'<br>free</td>';            
         echo '</td>';

}
```

Comment: Your missing `$stm->execute()`...

Comment: Learn to use bind variables, it'll make things easier

Comment: SQL-injection ole. My prefered part is, where you use POST-variables without validation directly within your query without escaping :) Use Prepared statements.

Comment: @KingCrunch, Mark Baker how I would I go about do this with my query

Comment: @TheShizy Oh, it's quite easy http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements Write the query with placeholders and bind the parameters/values.

Comment: If only there were any abstraction frontends which already solved such problems! (Also: `foreach` for arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat funny fact. Everyone only *mention* SQL injection and prepared statements while nobody wants to write the code :)

Though I could understand it: PDO is very weak with conditional queries, so the task is going to be quite toilsome.
Like any other API, PDO is good for basic tasks from beginner's manual only, and offers no real help to developer for whatever real life issues.

So, I'll give you a [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) example which is both **safe** and **convenient**.
It is **not** compatible with PDO, but you can use it instead and get all the benefits.

So, the idea is to *parse placeholders not in the whole query, but in the arbitrary query part only*. Say, for your facilities part:

```
$fac_sql = '';
foreach($array as $facility){   
    if ($facility) {
       $fac_sql .= $db->parse(' AND facilities_id=?i',$facility);
    }
}
```

Now you have syntactically correct statement in `$fac_sql` variable.
Same goes for the other parts

```
$cond = '';
if($park!="Any") {
    $cond .= $db->parse(' AND b.park_id=?s',$park);
}
if($lecturestyle_id!="Any") {
    $cond .= $db->parse(" AND lecturestyle_id=?s",$lecturestyle_id);
}
if($roomstructure_id!="Any") {
    $cond .= $db->parse(" AND roomstructure_id=?s",$roomstructure_id);
}
```

...as well as for the whole query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM ts_room rm
LEFT JOIN ts_roomfacilities rf
ON rm.id = rf.room_id
LEFT join ts_facilities f
ON f.id = rf.facilities_id
LEFT JOIN ts_building b
ON rm.building_id=b.id
WHERE capacity >= ?s;
?p
?p
AND rm.id NOT IN
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM ts_request rq
 LEFT JOIN ts_allocation a ON a.request_id = rq.id
 WHERE 
 day_id=1 AND period_id=?i
 OR a.status IS NOT NULL
 AND a.status IN ('Pending','Declined','Failed'))";

$rows = $db->getCol($sql,$group_size,$fac_sql,$cond,$i);
```

(code **not** tested, but only to serve as an example!).

Another safeMysql benefit is that it will return you both Mysql error message and whole query in case of error. You'll be able to either fix the error or try the query in the console for test.

So - this is how conditional queries have to be in general.

As for your particular problem with query - it's irrelevant to PDO or prepared statements or conditional query building. There is a flaw somewhere in the query logic.
You have to write your query in plain text and try it with console/phpadmin/sqlyog/whatever. You may ask for assistance for this **SQL** on stackoverflow as well.
As soon as you get your query working, you may start building it dynamically.

Also, I have a feeling that it's WAY overcomplex, and needs to be simplified. May be split into several easier queries. Also to run such a monster in a loop also a big flaw. Better to rewrite it in ONE call.